# Different ways of zooming in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, matrix, zooming

At the moment I'm achieving a zoom effect in OpenGL by translating the camera position into z direction based on some user input (keyboard functions). Now I've looked at several other examples that use zooming and got a little bit confused whether there are different ways of doing this: for example by changing the FOV with glm::perspective. Is there a difference between changing The fov and my z-translation, and if so, which way is better? What I also don't really understand is when to use glm::scale in the context of zooming, since I'm not using this either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm achieving a zoom effect in OpenGL by translating the camera position into z direction

That's not Zoom, that's Dolly. Zooming is the variation of the field of view, i.e. a change of the projection parameters.

> and if so, which way is better?

Neither, they're completely different movements. You can combine Dolly and Zoom to achieve that Dolly-Zoom Alfred Hitchcock got famous for. See this site for a list of camera movements:

http://www.mediacollege.com/video/shots/movement.html

Answer (score 0):

I've also created a zoom effect by scaling the world matrix.

ie to zoom 5x you could apply this matrix to the matrix stack:

```
  5    0   0   0
  0    5   0   0
  0    0   5   0
  0    0   0   1
```